# Finding the values of neurons using keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a very simple neural net:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='relu', input_dim=2)
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Basically I have an input layer with 2 values, a hidden layer with 2 neurons, and an output layer with one.

```
print(model.get_weights())
```

gives me the weights, while

```
print(model.predict(x)
```

gives me the value of the output layer.

I have trained the model and my weights are:

```
[[2.91677   3.9492033]
 [2.911809  3.9377801]]
```

The bias is:

```
[-2.9282627  1.0013505]
```

I calculated the values of input into the hidden layer for specific values by:

```
print(numpy.add(numpy.matmul(model.get_weights()[0], [0,0]), model.get_weights()[1]))
print(numpy.add(numpy.matmul(model.get_weights()[0], [1,0]), model.get_weights()[1]))
print(numpy.add(numpy.matmul(model.get_weights()[0], [0,1]), model.get_weights()[1]))
print(numpy.add(numpy.matmul(model.get_weights()[0], [1,1]), model.get_weights()[1]))
```

This gives me:

```
[-2.92826271  1.00135052]
[-0.01149273  3.91315949]
[1.02094054 4.93913066]
[3.93771052 7.85093963]
```

So, since I am using "relu", I expected that keras would give me

```
[0          1.00135052]
[0          3.91315949]
[1.02094054 4.93913066]
[3.93771052 7.85093963]
```

but when I do:

```
model_dense_2 = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs = model.layers[1].input)
pred_dense_2 = model_dense_2.predict([[0,0]], steps = 1) 
print(pred_dense_2) 

model_dense_2 = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs = model.layers[1].input)
pred_dense_2 = model_dense_2.predict([[1,0]], steps = 1) 
print(pred_dense_2) 

model_dense_2 = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs = model.layers[1].input)
pred_dense_2 = model_dense_2.predict([[0,1]], steps = 1) 
print(pred_dense_2) 

model_dense_2 = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs = model.layers[1].input)
pred_dense_2 = model_dense_2.predict([[1,1]], steps = 1) 
print(pred_dense_2)
```

I get:

```
[[0.        1.0013505]]
[[0.        4.950554]]
[[0.        4.939131]]
[[2.9003162 8.888334 ]]
```

So, I am ok with the first vector, The first coordinate of the second one is correct, but not the second one, the second coordinate of the third one is correct, but not the first one, and the fourth one is different.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Note that dense layers implement `X * W`, not `W * X` (* = matrix multiplication).

Comment: You are correct. I switched the matrix multiplication order. If you want to expand your comment into an answer, I will be happy to select it as the correct answer.